# Mail according to the device OS using Php

Tags: php, email

i got strucked with a task! can anyone help me out... if a user opens his emailid in iphone iwant to mail "hi", if the same user opens his email in android "hello" should be sent and if the user opens in windows "hey" should be sent.

"$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']" will gives the device info after clicking on it.. but the conditions should be worked before user gets a mail based on its device name.

Answer (score 0):

php and javascript will not work in the email. The only way you can achieve this behavior is that thisis an email  first it will store the data of the user such as name, email and etc. In this factor I will recommend when you get the user data include what device the user is using. In this way you can manipulate your greetings for the user.